# How can I parse url parameter when using flutter navigator 2.0?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am building flutter router based on this doc: https://techblog.geekyants.com/navigation-20-routing-on-flutter-web.

The question I have is that how can I get the url parameter on initial load? e.g. I have the url `http://localhost:8080?id=1234/#/user` which points to the path `/user` defined in `RouterDelegate`. I am able to open the related screen which is for `/user` but where should I parse the url parameter `id`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Uri class from dart:core

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Uri

ie: If `url = http://localhost:8082/game.html?id=15&randomNumber=3.14`

```
main() {
  print(Uri.base.toString()); // http://localhost:8082/game.html?id=15&randomNumber=3.14
  print(Uri.base.query);  // id=15&randomNumber=3.14
  print(Uri.base.queryParameters['randomNumber']); // 3.14
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whatever URL you enter in the browser it gets parsed in `RouteInformationParser`. In `RouteInformationParser` there is a method `parseRouteInformation()`,
in that method you will get the `RouteInformation` and you can parse the `RouteInformation` as

`final uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location);`

Then you can check the "id" here.
for eg -> let's say this is the route you have entered
http://localhost:8080?id=1234/#/user/2

```
 final id = uri.pathSegments.elementAt(1).toString();
```

This will give the id = 2;

For reference you can check the `parseRouteInformation` method code inside
`HomeRouteInformationParser (RouteInformationParser)` class in the article that you have mentioned.

Comment: I tried the method with this url `http://localhost:8080?id=1234/#/user/2`, but after type in the browser, it becomes `http://localhost:8080/#/user/2` and `id` parameter is wipped out.

Comment: I think thats not the right format of URL. Pramas should come after path resource. you can try this http://localhost:8080/#/user/?id=1234. Then you can get the "id" param as        


`final uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location);`

`id = uri.queryParameters["id"];` (as mentioned in one of the answers here)

Comment: or you can keep it like that just move the "#" http://localhost:52161/#/?id=12345/user here on doing `id = uri.queryParameters["id"];` you will get `id = "12345/user"` and you can get id out of it -> `uri.queryParameters["id"].split("/")[0]`